# Correlation of two categorical variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, agreement-statistics, paired-data

I have a list of N people, with two equivalent test performed (A and B), which can have as outcome 0 or 1 (cancer positive or negative). Test A is the accepted gold standard.

Is there any way to find if there are some kind of correlation between both? 
I found some solutions based on $\chi^2$, but I don't think that can be applied to this case. I also found some related solutions based on ROC curve analysis, but I think is far more complicated than what I need it.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from a more specific title - perhaps "measuring inter-rater reliability with binary data" or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to [image] you might also want to take a look into the [Phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient):

[image]

, where [image] is the total number of observations. This coefficient is specifically designed for binary variables and the logic behind it is that in the [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) behind the binary variables:

```
    B1   B0
 A1 n11  n10
 A0 n01  n00
```

, your data will be more "correlated" if it falls under the `n11->n00` diagonal. There are other similarity coefficients you might want to consider such as [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

In here you'll get a comprehensive list of some other possibilities.

[Measures for Binary Data](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_proximities_measures_binary_data.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a correlation specifically, the [tetrachoric correlation coefficient](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/tetra.htm) is meant for comparing two binary distributions (to estimate it you should have at least 50 observations).

You can calculate the tetrachoric correlation coefficient in R using the [polychor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/index.html) package:

`polychor(data, ML=T, std.err=T)`

Alternatively, the $\phi$ coefficient as suggested by @armatita is also the binary form of the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient. An alternate formulation from the $\chi^2$ one is the following:

$$
\phi=\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{n}}=\frac{ad-bc}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)(b+d)(c+d)}}
$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are defined by the following contingency table for tests $A$ and $B$:

$$
\begin{array}
~&A=1&A=0\\
B=1&a&b\\
B=0&c&d\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The normal test for association in binary data would be χ2, and as far as I can see this would seem to deliver the analysis you want. You may wish to undertake subsidiary analysis, including on any disagreement between tests A and B, but χ2 would be a reasonable first step. [There are other tests you could apply, but χ2 will do the job adequately, is simple and is well-understood.]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Using a $\chi^2$ test,  I need to make a contingency table and then will I not lose the fact that are paired observations?